# added link to image and text only

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

i have added a link to 6 images, with links to text as well. however the space next to the image is also click able which i don't want.

css:

```
#testimage a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}
#testimage1 a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}
#testimage2 a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}
#testimage3 a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}
#testimage4 a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}
#testimage5 a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}
#testimage6 a {width: 100%;  height: 100%;display: block;}

  #a1 a
 {position: absolute;font-size: 25px;fcolor: #085da2;top: 503px;}
 #a1 a:hover
 {color:#085da2;opacity:0.5;}
```

as you will see there the linking is not working properly for the images. as i only want image and text to be link, and nothing else, no white space!

any ideas

Comment: Use two separate links with the same target. You want two separate rectangular surfaces to be clickable, after all. Just wrap the image with an additional link.

Comment: i have 2 separate links, one for image and one for text. but when i however on white space its still showing its click able!

Comment: right! its because i have positioned my text, eg right 990px. so that makes it all a link!!! how do i only make text

Comment: Seriously, looking at the source code of that page, those links are your smallest problem. Not to mention two thirds of the relevant code aren't included in the question, propably because it's half a book considering you're using tons of id's instead of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gnmjk) (of both)

Firstly, just using a simple anchor tag inside the div with your text inside a heading tag

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-image">
  <a href="#"><h3>Events</h3></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-image a {
  height: 205px;
  width: 322px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #9ad499;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-image: url(http://mja.anytimeafter9.co.uk/sites/all/themes/MedicalJournalistsAssociation/images/mja1.jpg);
}

.bg-image a h3 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  color:black;
}
```

The other relies on more structure and an inline image (that is, in the HTML itself)

**HTML**

```
<div class="inline-image">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="  http://mja.anytimeafter9.co.uk/sites/all/themes/MedicalJournalistsAssociation/images/mja1.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>Events</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS** is similar with a couple of changes

```
.inline-image a {
  display: block;
  margin-left:10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #9ad499;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.inline-image img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.inline-image a h3 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  color:black;
}
```